# can not find corresponding collection of .wt file in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I found a huge .wt file in mongodb dbPath:

```
ubuntu@node11:~$ sudo ls -lah /data/shard-cluster-test/s0  | grep collection-14
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup  18G Oct 25 22:57 collection-14--5786157352597922030.wt
```

But I can not find `collection-14--5786157352597922030` in `db.printCollectionStats()`

I also tried to find the filename in the `stats()` of every collection in every database but can not find it.

I'm pretty sure there is no collection of that big size in my mongodb cluster, the biggest collection is 7.5GB and sharded into 3 shards, each about 2.8GB

So what is in the 18GB .wt file? Is it a corpse of a deleted collection? But the update time of the file is quite recent than any db operation.

Comment: `db.printCollectionStats()` only shows collections in the current database, did you check all of the databases listed by `show dbs`?

Comment: Yes, I checked all databases but no luck. Seems to be log data?